# Sharing object between dialogs of the same activity

Tags: android

In my small project I have one activity: `SomeActivity` and three
**custom dialogs**:`DialogA`,`DialogB`,`DialogC`.

Supposing DialogA has a `Foo Object` which needed to be sent to DialogB, and DialogC will receive this object after `DialogB` dismissed  then send it to `SomeActivity`.

I tried using interface but ended with spaghetti code.
I want some directions to do it properly.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] to show what you have so far.

Comment: the code is messy thats why i did not do that.

Comment: We can only give suggestions to fix the mess if you show it first.